# Swift 4 JSON decoding when type is only known at runtime

Tags: json, swift, swift4, swift-protocols, decodable

Is it possible with the [`Decodable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/decodable) protocol in Swift 4 to decode a JSON object when the type to decode to is *only* known at runtime?

I have a registry of sorts which maps a `String` identifier to the type we want to decode to, as below:

```
import Foundation

struct Person: Decodable {
    let forename: String
    let surname: String
}

struct Company: Decodable {
    let officeCount: Int
    let people: [Person]
}

let registry: [String:Decodable.Type] = [
    "Person": Person.self,
    "Company": Company.self
]

let exampleJSON = """
{
    "forename": "Bob",
    "surname": "Jones"
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

let t = registry["Person"]!

try! JSONDecoder().decode(t, from: exampleJSON) // doesn't work :-(
```

Am I on the right lines here or is there a better way?

Comment: You are supposed to pass `Person.self`
 instead of t

Comment: and change your Person properties to givenName and familyName

Comment: Yes, it of course works if I pass Person.self but the point is I am trying to do this dynamically at runtime. Also not sure what the names of the properties have to do with anything?

Comment: Didn’t say the name of the properties would change anything

Comment: As of Swift 5.6, this actually does work now

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your design is indeed unique but, unfortunately, I believe you are hitting an edge case of Swift's type system. Basically, a protocol doesn't conform to itself and, as such, your general `Decodable.Type` isn't enough here (i.e., you *really* need a concrete type to satisfy the type system requirements). This might explains the error you are having:

> Cannot invoke `decode` with an argument list of type `(Decodable.Type, from: Data)`. Expected an argument list of type `(T.Type, from: Data)`.

But, having said that, there is indeed a (dirty!) hack around this. First, create a dummy `DecodableWrapper` to hold your runtime-ish [`Decodable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/decodable) type:

```swift
struct DecodableWrapper: Decodable {
    static var baseType: Decodable.Type!
    var base: Decodable

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        self.base = try DecodableWrapper.baseType.init(from: decoder)
    }
}
```

then use it like this:

```swift
DecodableWrapper.baseType = registry["Person"]!
let person = try! JSONDecoder().decode(DecodableWrapper.self, from: exampleJSON).base
print("person: \(person)")
```

prints the expected result:

> person: Person(forename: "Bob", surname: "Jones")

Comment: @LeoDabus the properties come from the type returned by `registry["Person"]!`. My `DecodableWrapper` only *forwards* the decoding to his specific type, without assuming any specific data scheme.

Comment: No, it can't be anything but a `Person`-ish object. His code clearly assumes (i.e., `registry["Person"]`) that a person-like object will be decoded. He just doesn't know (at compile time) *which* type will hold said person. The jury is out on how useful such a dynamic mechanism will help him at all. But it's nice to know that *Swift 4 Coding framework* con work around such exotic design... ;)

Comment: I feel we would need further info -- from good @DaveRogers here -- to fully evaluate if this design will be a good fit for his overall architecture.

Comment: @LeoDabus ...yet another tool in the hacker's toolbox. Might come handy in rainy day, who knows? ;)

Comment: Thanks Paulo, this is a great step in the right direction! The static does feel a little bit dirty as you say but it'll do for now ;-)

Answer (score 10):

The [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46596926/106244) by Paulo has the disadvantage of it not being thread safe. Here's an example of a simpler solution that will allow you to decode a value without having the concrete type available:

```
struct DecodingHelper: Decodable {
    private let decoder: Decoder

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        self.decoder = decoder
    }

    func decode(to type: Decodable.Type) throws -> Decodable {
        let decodable = try type.init(from: decoder)
        return decodable
    }
}

func decodeFrom(_ data: Data, to type: Decodable.Type) throws -> Decodable {
    let decodingHelper = try JSONDecoder().decode(DecodingHelper.self, from: data)
    let decodable = try decodingHelper.decode(to: type)
    return decodable
}
```

Comment: Where can we modify this code to make it accept both single objects as well as arrays?