# Store Swift closures and cast them back to their original type

Tags: swift

I'm trying to create a class that can save different closures (or methods) with an argument of a specific subtype of `Decodable` that should be called later. This way I can predefine what actions, or methods, can be called on that class in response to some input. For example, the line `addCallback(setOption(_:), SetOptionRequest.self)` should result in the subsequent call to `try! performCallback("setOption", JSONEncoder().encode(SetOptionRequest())` to call `setOption(data)` where the argument `data` has type `SetOptionRequest`.

Here is the code I have so far (I took the bit about `DecodableWrapper` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46596926/656488)). The problem is that at runtime the cast `callback.callback as! (ActionRequest) throws -> Void` fails, since the type of the closure is not `(ActionRequest) throws -> Void` but `(SetOptionRequest) throws -> Void`. But I have no idea if and how I can cast the closure back to its original type. I considered using `Selector`s but I would like to keep the compile-time check that I'm binding methods with their correct argument type.

```
struct DecodableWrapper: Decodable {
    static var baseType: ActionRequest.Type!
    var base: ActionRequest

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        self.base = try DecodableWrapper.baseType.init(from: decoder)
    }
}

open class Server {

    private var actionCallbacks = [String: (callback: Any, dataType: ActionRequest.Type)]()

    open func setup() {
        addCallback(setOption, action: SetOptionRequestResponse.self)
    }

    public func addCallback<T: ActionRequest>(_ callback: @escaping (_ data: T) throws -> Void, action: T.Type) {
        actionCallbacks[T.action] = (callback, T.self)
    }

    private func performCallback(action: String, data: Data) throws {
        let callback = actionCallbacks[action]!
        DecodableWrapper.baseType = callback.dataType
        let data = try! JSONDecoder().decode(DecodableWrapper.self, from: data).base
        try (callback.callback as! (ActionRequest) throws -> Void)(data)
    }

    private func setOption(_ data: SetOptionRequest) {
    }

}

protocol ActionRequest {
    static var action: String
}

struct Request: SetOptionRequest {
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [this article](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/first-class-functions-in-swift/), I came up with a solution. The trick is to store a custom closure that always accepts the same argument type (in this case `Data`), does whathever needs to be done with the generic type `T` and then calls the nested closure.

```
open class Server {

    private var actionCallbacks = [String: (Data) throws -> Void]()

    open func setup() {
        addCallback(setOption)
    }

    public func addCallback<T: ActionRequest>(_ callback: @escaping (_ data: T) throws -> Void) {
        actionCallbacks[T.action] = { data in
            let data = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
            try callback(data)
        }
    }

    private func performCallback(action: String, data: Data) throws {
        if let callback = actionCallbacks[action] {
            try callback(data)
        }
    }

    private func setOption(_ data: SetOptionRequest) {
    }

}

public protocol ActionRequest: Codable {
    static var action: String { get }
}

struct SetOptionRequest: ActionRequest {
    static var action = "setOption"
}
```